# How do i Destroy the tls encryption key(session key) where https communication has been completed with springboot 2.7

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, encryption

I developed a simple Rest API controller as springboot.
The code is as follows.

```
@RequestMapping("/v1")
@RestController
public class AgentController {

  @PostMapping("/api/list")
  public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> getList(@RequestBody ApiRequest requestBody, HttpServletRequest request) {
     
      // some codes
      return response;
  }
}
```

My question is as follows.
I'm going to destroy the encryption key used in TLS communication, but I don't know how to access it.
I don't know if it's possible within the getList() function of the code or if I need to implement another class with the help of springboot.

I tried the following.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
System.out.println("1");
if (session != null) {
  System.out.println("2");
  SSLSession sslSession = (SSLSession) session.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.ssl_session");

   // Some codes..
}
```

However, the value of the "session" variable was always null.
How do i Destroy the tls encryption key(session key) where https communication has been completed with springboot 2.7.